# Validation not fired on OnSubmit , but it fired on OnVallidSubmit

Tags: blazor

I have simple form in blazor like below.

```
    <EditForm Model="@createInvoice"  OnValidSubmit="@CreateInvoice" >
    <DataAnnotationsValidator></DataAnnotationsValidator>
    <p>
        <label for="ddlService">Service</label>
        <InputSelect id="ddlService" @bind-Value="@createInvoice.SelectedService">
            <option value="0">Select Service</option>
            @foreach (var item in Services)
            {
                <option value="@item.ServiceId">@item.Name</option>
            }
        </InputSelect>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> createInvoice.SelectedService)"></ValidationMessage>
    </p>
</EditForm>
```

I am trying to validate form using data annotation attribute. 
Using OnSubmit of editform to submit form, but before submit the validation didn't trigger. 
If I use OnValidSubmit it does trigger validation.

Can someone explain how OnSumbit, OnValidSubmit and OnInvalidSubmit works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**OnSubmit** 
Is fired whenever you submit the form. When using this event, you are responsible for handling all the validation of the model.

**OnValidSubmit**
Is fired only when the model state is valid. When using this event all validation logic is called for you and the delegate you pass is only invoked if the model state is valid.

**OnInvalidSubmit**
Is fired when a submitted form is invalid.

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you mark it as the answer so others can see it resolved your issue, thanks.